# Handling Amazon ECS (Blue/Green) deployment failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

How do we handle failure when deploying a service with ECS blue/green deployment. Even after manually stopping the deployment the unhealthy task keeps of restarting. The only way I could stop the task from restarting is to perform a successful deployment. How do we handle such kind of situations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have details, but you can try to update you ECS Service's "Desired Count" to '0' manually and force new deployment from the ECS Console or CLI [1] which should stop ECS scheduler from constantly creating new Tasks and then terminating them if they are unhealthy.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html

Comment: thanks, setting desired count to 0 did stop the creation of new task. However I wasn't able to do a force deployment via cli as the service uses codeDeploy as deployment controller. What I did instead is deployed a stable version using codeDeploy and then reset the desired count to 1, thinks were back to normal. Another thing that I missed out earlier which could have made thinks simpler for me was, instead of choosing "Stop deployment" in codeDeploy I should have chosen  "Stop and rollback deployment". This would kill the replacement task set thus task wont keep restarting.